# How to do a linear regression in case of incomplete information about output variable

Tags: statistics, regression

I need to do a linear regression
y <- x1 + x2+ x3 + x4
y is not known
but instead of y we have f(y) which depends on y
for example, y is a probability from 0 to 1 of a binomial distribution over 0, 1
and instead of y we have (the number of 0, the number of 1) out of (the number of 0 + the number of 1) experiments
How should I perform linear regression to find correct y
How should I take into account the amount of information provided that for some x1 x2 x3 we have n experiments which give high confidence value of y, but for other x1 x2 x3 we have low confidence value of y due to small number of measurements

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need something like [BUGS](http://www.mrc-bsu.cam.ac.uk/bugs/) (Bayes inference Using Gibbs Sampling) for the unknown variable y.

Comment: Could you, please give more details?

Comment: Not really; you didn't give any actionable information in your question.  I guessed at a possible solution.  You said you have a distribution for y and some data for independent variables.  I'm proposing that you assume a fitting function and then do a Monte Carlo simulation that will result in distributions for the coefficients in the fitting function.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be asking for [logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression).